# Loop files and get the recent file based on the date

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop over the files and get the filename based on the recent date.

I have the list of files in a directory with a consistent format

```
  filename_XXX_20_01_2021.txt
  filename_XXX_03_03_2021.txt
  filename_XXX_03_02_2021.txt
  filename_XXX_04_01_2020.txt
  filename_XXX_20_01_2020.txt
```

I am trying to get the result filename_XXX_03_03_2021.txt because this is the recent file generated based on the date.

I tried the below command but this takes brings the file based on the "Changed" date.

```
 "latest_file=$(ls -t | head -n 1)"
```

Any suggestions/leads would be appreciated.

Comment: use ISO8601 notation for dates (YYYY-MM-DD), than you can just sort them alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain `bash`, without using any external command-line utilities, the script below will print the name of the latest file, based on the file name format specified in the question:

```
#!/bin/bash

suffix='[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'

latestdate=0
for file in *_$suffix; do
        IFS=_ read d m y <<< "${file#"${file%$suffix}"}"
        date=${y%.txt}$m$d
        ((date > latestdate)) && { latestdate=$date; latestfile=$file; }
done
echo "$latestfile"
```

Comment: Aydin: Once the for loop runs, I get the error "-bash: ((: 02_2021031003: value too great for base (error token is "02_2021031003")
-bash: ((: 03_2020031003: value too great for base (error token is "03_2020031003")
-bash: ((: 03_2021031003: value too great for base (error token is "03_2021031003")
"

Comment: @user3447653 Then I suspect the format of your filenames is not consistent. Can you give the *exact* filenames ? (a few of them)

Comment: projectname_extraction_1004_31_03_2020.txt, 
projectname_extraction_1002_31_03_2020.txt
projectname_extraction_1004_03_03_2021.txt
projectname_extraction_1002_03_03_2021.txt

Comment: @user3447653 Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort based on the filename, you can use this:

```
find -name 'filename*' -printf '%P\n' | sed -E 's/.*_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4}).txt/& \3-\2-\1/' | sort -k2V | cut -f1 -d' '
```

`find` looks to all files having `filename` as prefix.
`sed` appends a date field that can be sorted (e.g. for `20_01_2021` it adds `2021-01-20`)
`sort` reorder filename based on the added field date
`cut` removes the added date

Note that, if the files are created according to the filename date, you could avoid the `sed` command:

```
find -name 'filename*' -printf "%T+ %P\n" | sort | cut -f2 -d' '
```